# Asymptotics of $\sum_{k=m}^N u_k$ knowing the first term and $\frac {u_{k+1}}{u_k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, random-graphs

Lemma 1.3 in "Random graphs" by Frieze and Karoński contains the following treatment of asymptotics unclear to me.

> **Claim.** Let $n,m \in \mathbb N, N = \binom n2, p= \frac mN$. Define $$u_k = \binom Nk p^k (1-p)^{N-k}$$ Assume $m,\frac {N-m}{\sqrt m} \to \infty$, then for large $n$:
>
> $$\sum _{k=m}^{m+\sqrt m} u_k \geq \frac 13.$$

**Proof.** They notice $$u_m = \frac {1+o(1)}{\sqrt {2 \pi m}}.$$
and for $m \leq k \leq  m+\sqrt m$ they compute $$\frac {u_{k+1}} {u_k}\geq 1-o(1).$$

So I guess they want to bound $$\sum_{k=m}^{m+\sqrt m} u_k = \frac {1+o(1)}{\sqrt {2 \pi m}} (\sum_{t=0}^{\sqrt m} \prod_{j=0}^{t-1} \frac {u_{m+j+1}}{u_{m+j}})^k$$

### **Questions**

1. It seems we can simply argue that since $u_k = \frac {1+o(1)}{\sqrt {2 \pi k}}$, we have
   $$\sum u_k = \frac {1+o(1)}{\sqrt {2 \pi}} \int_m^{n+\sqrt m} \frac 1{\sqrt x} dx = \frac {1+o(1)}{\sqrt {2 \pi}} \sqrt {(m+\sqrt m) - \sqrt m} = \frac {1+o(1)}{\sqrt {2 \pi}} \frac{\sqrt {(m+\sqrt m) + \sqrt m}}{\sqrt m} \geq \frac {1+o(1)}{\sqrt {2 \pi}} \geq \frac 13.$$

Is this correct? And if so, why does the book use such a technical argument on bounding consecutive quotients?

2. How does the conclusion follow from the book's calculations?
3. Where does the integral of $e^{-x^2/2}$ come from in the end of the book's proof? (In the "spoiler" below)

### The excerpt from the book

> [image][image]

Comment: How many integer terms are between $[m,m+\sqrt{m}]$? And because $\frac{N-m}{\sqrt{m}} \rightarrow \infty$, do you agree that $\frac{N-m}{\sqrt{m}} \geq 1$ from some $N$ onwards?

Comment: Oh thank you @rtybase, that indeed explains why it is enough to consider the sum up to $m+\sqrt m$.

Comment: I edited to emphasize the remaining question.